# Interrupted Upgrade to 4.5.1

Tags: upgrade

I clicked the link from the dashboard to upgrade as I usually do, but instead of getting the usual download/install etc. messages, there was a delay and then this message:

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Now it (the WP site) thinks it is on the current version, but I was not convinced so I tried to Re-Install. This gets the error that an update is currently in progress. The only issue I found like this says it eventually cleared, but I have waited two days and still get the same error.

I do have a back up from the previous release, but would be very interested in any resolution less labor intensive.

Comment: I did a manual update and so am sure that the upgrade to 4.5.1 is complete (thanks for the suggestion. This did not, however, clear the problem with "another update is in progress". I will open another question on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to your files via ftp, you should be able to upgrade WordPress manually.

[According to WordPress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress), you can do so by swapping out a few folders and files:

> **Step 1: Replace WordPress files**
>
> 1. Get the latest WordPress zip (or tar.gz) file.
> 2. Unpack the zip file that you downloaded.
> 3. Deactivate plugins.
> 4. Delete the old wp-includes and wp-admin directories on your web host (through your FTP or shell access).
> 5. Using FTP or your shell access, upload the new wp-includes and wp-admin directories to your web host, in place of the previously
>    deleted directories.
> 6. Upload the individual files from the new wp-content folder to your existing wp-content folder, overwriting existing files. Do NOT delete
>    your existing wp-content folder. Do NOT delete any files or folders in
>    your existing wp-content directory (except for the one being
>    overwritten by new files).
> 7. Upload all new loose files from the root directory of the new version to your existing wordpress root directory.
>
> **Step 1.5: Remove .maintenance file**
>
> If you're upgrading manually after a failed auto-upgrade, delete the
> file .maintenance from your WordPress directory using FTP. This will
> remove the "failed update" nag message.
>
> **Step 2: Update your installation**
>
> Visit your main WordPress admin page at /wp-admin. You may be asked to
> login again. If a database upgrade is necessary at this point,
> WordPress will detect it and give you a link to a URL like
> http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/upgrade.php. Follow that link
> and follow the instructions. This will update your database to be
> compatible with the latest code. You should do this as soon as
> possible after step 1.
>
> Don't forget to reactivate plugins!
>
> **Step 3: Do something nice for yourself**
>
> If you have caching enabled, clear the cache at this point so the
> changes will go live immediately. Otherwise, visitors to your site
> (including you) will continue to see the old version (until the cache
> updates).
>
> Your WordPress installation is successfully updated. That's as simple
> as we can make it without Updating WordPress Using Subversion.
>
> Consider rewarding yourself with a blog post about the update, reading
> that book or article you've been putting off, or simply sitting back
> for a few moments and letting the world pass you by. Final Steps
>
> Your update is now complete, so you can go in and enable your Plugins
> again. If you have issues with logging in, try clearing cookies in
> your browser. Troubleshooting
>
> If anything has gone wrong, then the first thing to do is go through
> all the steps in our extended upgrade instructions. That page also has
> information about some of the most common problems we see.
>
> If you run into a request for FTP credentials with trying to update WP
> on a IIS server automatically, it may well be a matter of rights. Go
> into the IIS Management Console, and there to the application pool of
> your blog. In its advanced settings, change the Process Model Id into
> LocalSystem. Then on Sites, choose your blog, right click, click on
> Edit permissions and on security tab add authenticated users. That
> should do it.
>
> If you experience problems after the upgrade, you can always restore
> your backup and replace the files with ones from your previous version
> from the release archive.